# How to do an espresso test on an Array Adapter within an SearchSpinner?

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso, coded-ui-tests

```
onView(withId(R.id.spinnerStates)).check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)));
onView(withId(R.id.spinnerStates)).perform(click()); onView(isAssignableFrom(EditText.class)).perform(typeText(stateCode), closeSoftKeyboard());

 onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(String.class)), is(stateCode))).perform(click());
```

I want to test the searchspinner with espresso, but when the test run, the spinner is  empty, and it shows me this errorr: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'is assignable from class '.